# Why up to index_granularity * 2 extra rows will be read for ClickHouse primary key?

Tags: primary-key, clickhouse

According to [ClickHouse documentation](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/), when reading a single range of the primary key, up to `index_granularity * 2` extra rows in each data block can be read.

Why `index_granularity * 2` extra rows? I can't figure this out.

> Take the `(CounterID, Date)` primary key as an example. In this case,
> the sorting and index can be illustrated as follows:
>
> ```
>   Whole data:     [---------------------------------------------]
>   CounterID:      [aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbcdeeeeeeeeeeeeefgggggggghhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiikllllllll]
>   Date:           [1111111222222233331233211111222222333211111112122222223111112223311122333]
>   Marks:           |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |
>                   a,1    a,2    a,3    b,3    e,2    e,3    g,1    h,2    i,1    i,3    l,3
>   Marks numbers:   0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10
> ```
>
> If the data query specifies:
>
> - `CounterID in ('a', 'h')`, the server reads the data in the ranges of marks `[0, 3)` and `[6, 8)`.
> - `CounterID IN ('a', 'h') AND Date = 3`, the server reads the data in the ranges of marks `[1, 3)` and `[7, 8)`.
> - `Date = 3`, the server reads the data in the range of marks `[1, 10]`.
>
> The examples above show that it is always more effective to use an
> index than a full scan.
>
> **A sparse index allows extra data to be read. When reading a single range of the primary key, up to `index_granularity * 2` extra rows in
> each data block can be read.**

[Primary Keys and Indexes in Queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHyxa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the edge case on this example:

```
  CounterID:      [aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabcdeeeeeeeeeeeeefggggg]
  Date:           [1111111222222233331233211111222222333211111]
  Marks:           |      |      |      |      |      |      |
                  a,1    a,2    a,3    b,3    e,2    e,3    g,1
  Marks numbers:   0      1      2      3      4      5      6
```

Query with condition *CounterID = 'b'* will read data in the range [2, 4) where just one row is target but *(index_granularity * 2)* are extra ones.

In this example *index_granularity* (it is the number of data rows between the marks of an index) is *6*.